# i386 C process - What happens in the remaining 1 GB of addressable space?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

It's documented that variables allocated on the heap are stored in the low address area and grow towards the stack and vice versa. I decided to test this out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char my_const_global_var = '0';
char my_global_var = '0';

int main(void) {
    char my_stack_var = '0';
    char* my_heap_var = (char*) malloc(1);
    *my_heap_var = '0';
}
```

It appears that `my_const_global_var` and `my_global_var` are addressed in the low address area (shortly after `000XXXXX` and before the heap) but what surprises me is that `my_stack_var` is addressed **exactly** around the 75% mark (around `bffbdaXX)`. I'm guessing I'll get a segfault when my global/heap/stack variables exceed 3 GB of memory, so I did a search and found mention of [a 3 GB barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier) but no mention of what happens in the remaining 1 GB of addressable space.

What happens in the remaining 25% of the memory address space?

Comment: In a 32-bit system only 3.5 GB are addressable (without PAE). Presumably, the non-addressable 512 MB you see is reserved for the OS. Linux/Unix systems reserve 10% of resources for root.

Comment: Depends on the platform. Linux and Windows use different approaches (and Windows is configurable). Also depends on the host operating system - 32-bit processes on a 32-bit OS can get one behavior, while 32-bit processes running on a 64-bit OS can get a different behavior.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 3.5GB is not a standard user-mode/kernel-mode split. You may be thinking of the fact that 32-bit OSes can't use a full 4GB of physical RAM without PAE (due to memory-mapped devices taking some of the physical address space), but that's not what this question is about - and the amount depends on the specific devices installed in a given system. It is not fixed at 3.5GB.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes, I was thinking of the video memory being mapped backward from the top of the 4gb stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Protected mode operating systems running on 32-bit x86 CPUs usually divide the 32-bit virtual address space into to two main regions. The first is for user processes and the second is for the kernel. The virtual address space doesn't address physical memory directly. Instead it's mapped through a page table maintained by the kernel to physical memory. This allows the operating system to give each process its own virtual address space, isolating them from each other. When it switches processes it changes page tables so that the user area of the virtual address space points to the physical memory locations used by the new process.

However when it switches processes, the operating system doesn't change page table entries that correspond to the kernel region. This means that while each process has its own physical memory mapped into the user region, the kernel region remains the same for each process. Mapping the kernel memory into the virtual address space of each process allows for much quicker transition from user mode to kernel mode when performing system calls. If the kernel wasn't mapped into every process, the operating system would essentially have to switch processes (to a hypothetical kernel "process") to perform a system call. Switching processes is a much more expensive operation than just transitioning from user mode to kernel mode.

Most 64-bit x86 operating systems also have similar split, but since they have much bigger a virtual address space they divide the virtual address space into much larger chunks. When running 32-bit programs these operating systems usually give the program access to all or nearly all of the first 4 GB of virtual address space.

Note that how virtual memory is split into user and kernel regions is unaffected by the amount of physical memory in the system. Unless explicitly configured differently, a machine with only 64 MB of RAM will have the same user/kernel virtual address space split as a machine with 64 GB of memory when running the exact same operating system.

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, 32-bit processes only have 4GB of RAM if they were linked with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` option, otherwise they still have 2GB RAM limit like in 32-bit Windows. I also heard that Solaris "maps user-space and kernel-space into distinct 4GB address spaces" https://www.quora.com/Why-do-32-bit-Linux-kernels-only-recognize-3GB-of-RAM

Comment: Solaris on Ultra Sparc CPUs uses separate address spaces for user and kernel, but the Sparc CPU has special hardware support for that. Solaris on x86 CPUs (and older Sparcs) uses a split user/kernel address space. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3024/6j2sumi4b/index.html